# Legendre polynomial : show by recurrence that $P_n(1) = 1$

Tags: orthogonal-polynomials

Starting from the recurrent relation of Legendre polynomial :

> $(n+1)P_{n+1}(x) - (2n+1)xP_n(x) + nP_{n-1}(x) = 0 $ for $n \geq 1$ with $P_0(x) = 1$ and $P_1(x) = x$

How can I show by recurrence that $P_n(1) = 1$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply: take any $n\in\Bbb N$, $n\ge 2$, and assume $P_{n}(1)=P_{n-1}(1)=1$. Then for $x=1$ we get
$(n+1)P_{n+1}(1)-(2n+1)+n=0$, hence trivially $P_{n+1}(1)=1$ by the induction argument.

Comment: How can I assume that $P_{n-1}(1) = 1$ ?

Comment: This is the version of Induction Theorem. Suppose (for simplicity) that $0\in\Bbb N$. Let $A\subset\Bbb N$ with $0\in A$ and for any $n\in\Bbb N$, $\{0,\dots,n\}\subset A$ implies that $n+1\in A$. Then $A=\Bbb N$.